# I get a "daily edit creation quota exceeded" error even though i don't break the limits

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api

For several days now i get this output:

```
C:\Users\bla\Desktop\Rocstar\google-apple-api>pipenv run python test-google-apis.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bla\Desktop\Rocstar\google-apple-api\test-google-apis.py", line 56, in <module>
    edits_create_response = service.edits().insert(packageName = app).execute()
  File "C:\Users\bla\.virtualenvs\google-apple-api-LxGzJBGW\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\_helpers.py", line 134, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\bla\.virtualenvs\google-apple-api-LxGzJBGW\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 935, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/bla.apk.bla/edits?alt=json returned "Daily edit creation quota exceeded.". Details: "Daily edit creation quota exceeded.">
```

in a script in which i intend to extract some basic information from several published apps.

This script has been working for several weeks before starting to print this error.

I tried the following:

- Cooldown of 5 days before requesting any api again
- Changing the private keys that i use for the requests
- Making only one request instead of several as it is in the script

But i still get the same error. I checked the cloud consle dashboards, and quotes and i can confirm that i'm not even close to breaking any of them (200.000 daily and 60 per hour is my understanding)

Any help would be more than welcomed. Thanks in advance

Comment: The error related to the limit/quota is not documented. I suggest opening an [issuetracker report](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) with the correct components. Provide reproduction steps if possible and a snippit of  the code that calls the API. It would be nice to provide an answer here once you get a clarification for the benefit of the community.

Answer (score 0):

Finally was able to debug the issue with my script. It WAS NOT API related, the issue was that someone in my team created manually a draft of a version of one of the apps, and so the script had an error while fetching the information of this app.
Since it was in a loop the daily quota of api calls was exceeded everyday.
Solution was to delete this draft manually from the console and also update the script in order to prevent this from happening again